# Transferring Xcode Project from one computer to another brings random errors?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a Xcode project I got from another developer. Initially when I opened it it has a bunch of errors (most of which were un-updated frameworks). I got it to work after a while and I fixed it. I want pass it back to the manager since I'm leaving uni in a few months. I copied it over to my friends Mac to see what would happen if I just took the project and all it's folders and made it a zipfile. It didn't work for some reason. It gave me an error:

```
error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported
```

But why did that come up? I mean it's the same code on the slightly different versions of Xcode (13.1 versos 14.1) but I doubt there was a massive change between the two that would cause this. I want to be able to pass these app later in the future without having to care about this stuff. I made a GitHub (link below) would cloning that work? Also the laptop I chose was just a fresh reset. Would it be due to not having coco-pods installed?

I feel like I could go through and fix it all on that laptop and document that but then I'm afraid that every time I put it on a new one it would come up with random errors every single time making my documentation moot.

https://github.com/AbdullahMSaid/SonicExperiment-Works

With big help this was Fixed.

Things that fixed it.

1. Having the correct version of Xcode
2. Turning everything from absolute path to relative
3. Lots of other code fixes. But those are my project specific.

Comment: I don’t know what the problem is but 13.1 -> 14.1 is not a trivial change. It’s a full version difference and since the error is specific about something being unsupported I’d upgrade to the same Xcode versions and see if that improved things. I forgot to ask which version was the app written in originally?

Comment: It was written in a version from like last year. I'm updating the copy (hoping it won't break it). I have slow wifi and I'll respond when I check

Comment: You were right also. The version Xcode I was running definitely did matter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need bridging headers in framework. Use should have something like "YourFramework.h" where you can import your .h files.

Comment: I have OpenCvWrapper.h the riding header just has 1 line '#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"' how should I switch over to a non bridging header?